# Difference between accessing variable inside a function by passing as argument and global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, arguments, closures

What is the difference of accessing variables inside the function by as argument and without argument?

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

function x() {
    var c = a + b;
    console.log(c)
}

function y(a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    console.log(c)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference here is that `y` does not use anything other than the arguments provided to the function. As soon as you see the function call - say `y(1, 2)` - you know exactly what will happen. (Assuming at least that you are reasonably familiar with the function and what it does - but even if you aren't familiar with it, hopefully it has a name that makes it sufficiently clear.)

The contrast with `x` is that it reads from external (here global) variables `a` and `b`. In other words, it depends on inputs that are not explicitly provided to the function. This makes it much harder to understand what a call to `x()` will do, because it depends on the value of `a` and `b` - which may be assigned quite some distance away in the program. Indeed, perhaps their values can be changed, in different ways, and by other functions - in which case it is impossible to know exactly what `x()` will do without carefully studying the entirety of the program up until that call. Again, contrast that with `y` where we need only look at the call site, and nothing else.

While, in some practical situations, it is hard to avoid some sort of "global state", avoiding it as much as possible, and trying to keep the information that a function needs local to it - as in `y` - is unquestionably better design. It makes the code much easier to understand, and therefore much less likely to have bugs in it.

Answer (score 2):

> Javascript always **pass by value** so changing the value of the variable never changes the underlying primitive (String or number).

If you modify `variables` inside the function that is passed as argument then it does not change the value of orignal variable(Pass by value).

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

function x() {
  var c = a + b;
  a = c;
  console.log(c)
}


function y(a, b) {
  var c = a + b;
  var a = c;
  console.log(c)

}

y(a, b)
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
x()
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the scope of your second function, `a` and `b` refer to the arguments, not the global variables.

```js
var a = 1
var b = 2

function exampleOne () {
  console.log("example 1: ", a, b)
}

function exampleTwo (a, b) {
  console.log("example 2: ", a, b)
}

exampleOne()
exampleTwo(3, 4)
exampleTwo()
```

Answer (score 2):

The 3 cases have different purposes, some non exhaustive:

1. Inside a function:

Only if the variable have to be unloaded after the function call, unless it be returned

```
function helloworld() {
  const words = ['hello', 'world'];
  return words.join(' ');
}
```

2. As argument:

Every time you want to use an external value which change the result

```
 function hello(name) {
   return 'Hello ' + name;
 }
```

3. From closure:

In others cases:

```
 // inside a lambda
 function upperThan(array, n) {
   return array.filter(item => item > n);
 }

 // use a constant
 const HELLO = 'Hi';
 function sayHello(name) {
   return HELLO + ' ' + name;
 }
```